# Sign data by cms

Tags: java, cryptography, pkcs#7

I am really newbie in encryption topic. My company give me a `.cer` file per user and want to sign pkcs#7 each request we send to bank behalf of that user.
So, What can I do? can you give me a hint?

Comment: Use a library that supports CMS such as Bouncy Castle and start typing.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you martin. But That library need a private key and x509certificate. I am really not sure that my `.cer` file is private key or x509?

Comment: It's undoubtedly x509, but yeah, you need a private key for signing. Maybe you've been given a CA certificate for which you need to generate a key pair and a certificate request? Mind you, my icon displays an owl staring through the screen at you, but I still cannot read the information you have.